# String to date() function not return correct ISO Date

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, project

```
                {
                 $addFields: {
                   date: {$substr : ["$visits.visit_date", 0,10]}
                 }
               },
                {
                    $project:{
                        now: new Date(),
                        returns: new Date("2017-09-14"),
                        visit_date: "$visits.visit_date",
                        //dateDifference: { $subtract: [ new Date(), "$visits.visit_date" ] },

                        split: "$date",
                        dates: new Date("$date")
                    }
                }
```

This project return

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a26856f462c9616abc98d60"),
    "now" : ISODate("2017-12-06T22:21:31.499-06:30"),
    "returns" : ISODate("2017-09-13T17:30:00.000-06:30"),
    "visit_date" : "2017-09-14 18:37:58",
    "split" : "2017-09-14",
    "dates" : ISODate("1969-12-31T17:30:00.000-06:30")
}
```

**see this here i get trouble it's not a correct output**

> "dates" : ISODate("1969-12-31T17:30:00.000-06:30")

**because i get correct output while manually add a string**

> "returns" : ISODate("2017-09-13T17:30:00.000-06:30"),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new Date("$date") evaluated before this is passed to mongodb aggregation pipeline and till then "$date" is just a normal string to javascript engin

for mongodb 3.6 you can use

```
db.coll.aggregate([
{
  $project:{

  date:{
         $dateFromString: {
            dateString: "$visits.visit_date"
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error  'Unrecognized expression '$dateFromString'

Comment: mongodb 3.6 required

Comment: my latest version is 3.4 i try to upgrade but it's not done?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your code in the top box is incomplete.

Are you trying to set date at one place in the structure at the same time as using it elsewhere?